# RegEx multiple matches after positive lookbehind possible (after word-wrap)?

Tags: c#, regex

I am new to regular expressions and have the following problem with it:

Text file which is being parsed:

```
KeywordA:   123
    93  0   0   524 0   0   78  0   0   6789    0   0
KeywordB:   456
    93  0   0   524 0   0   78  0   0   6789    0   0
KeywordC:   789
    93  0   0   524 0   0   78  0   0   6789    0   0
```

Now I would like to get all numbers with 2 or more digits in the next line after "KeywordB: 456".

I tried the expression `/(?<=KeywordB:\t456\n\t)(\d{2,})/g`

But with that one I only get the first number (and only because the 93 is a number with more than one digit).

Is it even possible to get all appropriate matches with RegEx where you want to have multiple matches with a pattern after a pattern and do word-wrapping or have I missed something fundamental?

Comment: C#...I tried to realize the regex with regex101.com firstly

Comment: Bad idea, regex101 isn't designed for C#, use regexstorm.net/tester instead. add the C# tag to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With .net you can use variable-length lookbehinds:

```
(?<=^KeywordB:\s*456\r?\n.*)\b\d{2,}
```

(with the multiline option)

[demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3f%3c%3d%5eKeywordB%3a%5cs*456%5cr%3f%5cn.*)%5cb%5cd%7b2%2c%7d&i=KeywordA%3a+++123%0d%0a++++93++0+++0+++524+0+++0+++78++0+++0+++6789++++0+++0%0d%0aKeywordB%3a+++456%0d%0a++++93++0+++0+++524+0+++0+++78++0+++0+++6789++++0+++0%0d%0aKeywordC%3a+++789%0d%0a++++93++0+++0+++524+0+++0+++78++0+++0+++6789++++0+++0&o=m)

Comment: Hmm on second thought I have to admit that your RegEx makes more sense with the use of C#. But the one of Josh is also perfectly usable.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [the `\G` anchor](http://www.regular-expressions.info/continue.html) in order to continue matching at the end of the previous match:

```
KeywordB:\t456\n|\G\t(?:(\d{2,})|\d)
```

[**.NET Fiddle Example Here**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/SFfGIa)

You can also remove the positive lookbehind since you're just retrieving the values in the first capturing group.

**Explanation:**

- `KeywordB:\t456\n|\G` - Match `KeywordB:\t456\n` or the start of the previous match (`\G`).
- `\t` - Match the tab, `\t`, after `KeywordB:\t456\n` or the end of the previous match.
- `(?:` - Start of a non-capturing group.
- `(\d{2,})|\d` - Capturing group for two or more digits **or** match a single digit (in other words, if two or more digits aren't captured, match a single digit and move on).
- `)` - End of a non-capturing group.

Output based on the data you provided:

```
93
524
78
6789
```

Code snippet used in the example above:

```
string pattern = @"KeywordB:\t456\n|\G\t(?:(\d{2,})|\d+)";
string input = @"KeywordA:  123
    93  0   0   524 0   0   78  0   0   6789    0   0
KeywordB:   456
    93  0   0   524 0   0   78  0   0   6789    0   0
KeywordC:   789
    93  0   0   524 0   0   78  0   0   6789    0   0";

foreach (Match match in Regex.Matches(input, pattern))
{
    string groupOne = match.Groups[1].Value;

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(groupOne))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(groupOne);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This is what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

I thought I'd throw this in as an alternative, so I know it's not a direct answer to the question. But could you use LINQ?

```
File
    .ReadAllLines("file.txt")
    .SkipWhile(line => line != "KeywordB:   456")
    .Skip(1)
    .Take(1)
    .SelectMany(line => line.Split(' ', '\t'))
    .Where(part => part.Length >= 2)
    .ToArray();
```

With your input I get:

> 93, 524, 78, 6789

I almost always find a LINQ solution far more readable than regex.

Comment: Thanks for the input and interesting approach :-)

Comment: @flauros - No worries. I do think that it is telling that the LINQ solution is the only one with an up-vote at this time. I really do think that Regex is awesome and can be very useful, but it is arcane and a write-once technology. It's very hard to just glance at and know that it works. The LINQ, on the other hand, you can read line-by-line and work it out.